# Problems with return value C

Tags: c

Getting problem with return (huge) value. I have already checked at the enthernet, but found nothing :( Hoping that here I could find answer to my question. I am just beginner, so hard to do something right if you dont know what is wrong ((

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


void MasivaIzveide (int *masivs, int x )
{
int  i, reiz,n1,n2; 

srand(time(NULL));
/* nosaka cik elementu masiva bus */  
printf("Ievadi, divus masiva emelentus, kuri bus '0' starp kuram bus summa\n\n");
printf("\n Pirmais elements=");
scanf("%d", &n1);
printf("\n Otrais elements=");
scanf("%d", &n2);




  for ( i = 0; i < x; i++ )
 {

  masivs[ i ] = rand() % 200-100 ; /* random vertibas katram masiva skaitlim*/
  masivs[n1]= 0;
  masivs[n2]=0;
  printf("Loceklis[%d] = %d\n", i, masivs[i] );
  } 



return;   
}



void Reizinajums (int *masivs, int x) {
int i, reiz;
reiz=masivs[2];
for (i=4; i < x; i=i+2) {
reiz=reiz*masivs[i] ;
}   
printf("\n\nReizinajums ir %d\n\n\n\n ", reiz);
return;
}
void main(){
int i,j,s;
int masivs[i];
printf("Tiks izveidots masiivs\n\n\n\n");
MasivaIzveide(masivs,15);
Reizinajums(masivs,15);
return;
}
```

The problem is at the line (reiz=reiz*masivs[i] ;)
I am using pointers aswell. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: What happens? I assume it compiles. What happens when it runs?

Comment: All your functions return `void` (which, for `main` is an error).  So what do you mean by “huge return value”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a mistake:

```
int i,j,s;
int masivs[i];
```

You are declaring `masivs` with the dimension `i` but that is an uninitialized variable. That causes undefined behaviour. Perhaps you meant:

```
int masivs[15];
```

You should also check that `n1` and `n2` are in the correct range before using them as array indices.